# Hold selected text button add-on building

Tags: ios, customization

In IOS, we can select text and press it, which will open a small bubble with a list of buttons. As shown in the image.
[image]
I want to add a button that leads to my own software. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I do not believe Apple has made a setting that allows you to edit that menu. If you are looking for a way to do this *programmatically* you will need to ask this on stack overflow.com (as it is a question about software development) or on Apple's developer discussion boards.